# Initializing a shopping bag

Tags: meteor

in my `/app.js`

I initialize a shopping bag like below

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    var bag = Session.get("shoppingBag") || {};
    console.log(bag)
    Session.set("shoppingBag", bag);
  });
}
```

and I add to the shopping bag in another page

```
  Template.ProductDetail.events({
    'click button.add-to-bag': function (event, template) {
      var productId = template.data._id;
      var bag = Session.get("shoppingBag");
      if (!(productId in bag)) {
        bag[productId] = true;
      }
      Session.set("shoppingBag", bag);
      $('.msg').fadeIn().fadeOut();
    },
  });
```

However, I found out that everytime I refresh a page, the startup code is re-run. As far as I understand, the session should still be preserved after a refresh and `var bag = Session.get("shoppingBag") || {};` should not return an empty object. What am I doing wrong? Can anyone explain what's happening here?

Answer (score 1):

The name Session is a really bad name, it doesn't work the way you expect. If you want such behaviour you can use this package: https://github.com/okgrow/meteor-persistent-session

Keep in mind that this package will save EVERYTHING, so don't forget to initialise your KeyValues for Session at the template `created` callback.

I suggest that you use a ReactiveDict per Template and also use it on the child templates. Meteor is going to make `vars` available on the next release for this purpose. You'll find that it's very easy to collide if you use Session for everything.

Comment: What do you think about using a local collection to store the items?
`ShoppingBag = new Mongo.Collection(null);`

Comment: Same issue, it won't be saved anywhere. You should consider LocalStorage for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Like Mario suggested, I had to use `localStoarge` because both `Session` and local collection are not permanent in Meteor. However, I also needed the reactive nature of `Session` I had to do the following.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    try {
      var bag = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shoppingBag"));
    } catch (e) {
      var bag = {};
    }
    bag = bag || {};
    Session.set("shoppingBag", bag);
  });
}
```

After each refresh we will look at `localStorage`. When storing

```
  var bag = Session.get("shoppingBag");
  Session.set("shoppingBag", bag);
  localStorage.setItem("shoppingBag", JSON.stringify(bag)); //localStoarge only take string key:value pairs
```

Make sure you store in localStorage as well as the `Session`. Finally,

```
  Template.Bag.helpers({
    bagged_products: function () {
      var bag = Session.get("shoppingBag") || {};
      ...
    }
  })
```

This ensures that everytime `Session` is updated, this helper is called again.